# How can I best physically box in my internet router

Tags: routers

I have a router standing in a corner on the floor. There are a few wires lying on the floor. Its ugly, it collects a lot of dust and when children are visiting they get in and mess my signal up. All my tv signals are also connected here.

I would like to have some sort of box-like contraption around it. But I am afraid that it will weaken the wireless signal strength. Is there any particular recommended material to use or avoid?

Anyone have a more creative idea than to just stuff it into some crate?

Thank you

Comment: If your router/AP has an external antenna, you can get one with a wire and keep that part outside the box. That said a wood does not attenuate the signal that much: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/6231/12118

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure the device(s) get convection air for cooling.

I have one of those Ikea bookshelves that has a lot of squares and open backs.  The router is on one shelf, all the cables behind, boxed in by self-contained trays (so they don't lean in and block its airflow).  It's not trivial but not hard to pull the router out to get to the cables.  No one would play there by accident.

Wood, paper and plastic attenuate the signal only a little.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a box very similar to a dresser drawer - only using peg board for the front, top and bottom.
Or you might modify an old drawer and simply cover the top with peg board - drill holes in the back for your cables.